# problem with onKeyDown

Tags: android

My aim here is that I want this `Activity` to be able to move around and show the toasts while the user navigates the map, but as soon as he hits the center key, it should return the last value that the user touched.

Its not working for some reason, and when I put `onKeyDown` inside the if loop, it gives errors. How do I get it to work?

```
    public class createNote extends MapActivity {

    MapView mapview;
    String sLatt;
    String sLonn;

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }       

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStates){       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceStates);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        mapview=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.MapView);
        mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapOverlay mapoverlay=new mapOverlay();
        List<Overlay>listOfOverlays=mapview.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapoverlay);


    }   


    class mapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay{
        @Override

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapview){
            GeoPoint p=null;

            if (event.getAction()==1){
                 p=mapview.getProjection().fromPixels((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6 + "," + p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            double lat=(double) (p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
            double lon=(double) (p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);

            String sLat=Double.toString(lat);
            String sLon=Double.toString(lon);
            sLatt=sLat;
            sLonn=sLon;

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),sLat + "-" + sLon,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            //setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().setAction(sLat + "," + sLon));
            //setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().setAction("test"));
            //Intent data = new Intent();
            //data.putExtra("key1", sLat);
            //data.putExtra("key2", sLon);
            //setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
            //finish();



            }



            return false;
        }

        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
             super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event, mapview);
             if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){
                    Intent data = new Intent();
                    data.putExtra("key1", sLatt);
                    data.putExtra("key2", sLonn);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
                    finish();
                    return true;
             }
             else return false;

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your activity needs to implement the OnKeyListener and then you can override the onKeyDown().

Comment: You mean it was just using it default action when I pressed it, and the code I write was ingored?

Comment: Also, this might sound noobish but I'm new to java and get confused. I implement the onkeylistener class outside the ontouchevent class? and inside the onkeylistener i put the onkeydown?

Comment: This is the kind of code you need.
=================================
    public class <Your activity> extends Activity implements OnKeyListener {

@Override
 public boolean onKey(View V, int keycode, KeyEvent event) {

  if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    && (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)) {
  
   //Your code goes here
  }

 }

}    Please ignore the formattinmg :)

Answer (score 0):

You are placing `onKeyDown` inside the `mapOverlay` class instead of the `Activity`.

Comment: Overlooked that. Stupid me. I changed it so that its under Activity class and did Override, but it still doesn't respond.